# Auth0 & Apollo-client library issue in angular "There are no queryparams available for parsing"

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo, auth0

I am currently working on a little project trying to implement auth0 authentication in my angular frontend. So far it works stellar, however, when I installed the apollo-client package using `ng add apollo-client` the redirect from auth0 back to my application gives an error, and I am not logging in:

[image]
I want to use the apollo client to connect the front end to my backend graphql api. I have these packages installed, and use the default auth service provided in [the quickstart guide for angular from auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login).

[image]

I have no idea what can be causing this, if there is any need for additional source let me know.
Thank you so much if you can help me out.

Kind regards
Pim Schwippert

Comment: I am having the same problem. @auth0/auth0-spa-js 1.9.0 (package-lock.json). I'm not using apollo. I'm having the issue with development but the deployed version is working fine.

Comment: I downgraded @auth0/auth0-spa-js from 1.9.0 to 1.8.1 and it has been working for me

Comment: alright I will look into this, thanks for the advice

Comment: Here's a [link to an issue on their github](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/issues/225) you might need too. `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false }) ],`